# error 405 apache cordova sending post

Tags: cordova, post, tornado, phonegap, http-status-code-405

i'm triying to send a JSON from cordova to tornado, the source code is on a .js file like this:

```
$http.post('http://localhost:81/api/login/validate', {
    user: user,
    password: password,
}).success(function(response) {
   $scope.loginValidate = response;
});
```

then a .py file manage the handler request:

class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

```
def set_default_headers(self):
    origin = self.request.headers.get('Origin', '*')
    if origin == 'null':
        origin = '*'  
    SUPPORTED_METHODS = ("CONNECT", "GET", "HEAD", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH", "PUT", "OPTIONS")
    self.set_header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000")
    self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" )
    self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE")
    self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With") # , application/json -Json
    self.set_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
```

but i get an error 405 method not allowed, the code works fine whit angularjs, but when runing it on cordova it show the error.

Also i allready has installed the whitelist API, configuring the config.xml file like this:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

and a package.json like this:

```
"proxy": [
   {
     "path": "/api",
     "proxyUrl": "http://192.168.10.246:81/api/*"
   }
],
"defaultBrowser": "firefox",
```

Comment: Have you created a `post` method in your handler class to handle `POST` requests?